# Identifying attachments in WEBDav result

Tags: php, exchange-server, webdav

Using the WEBDav libraries from [Troy Wolf](http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/exchange_webdav_examples.php)

I am using the following query to pull results from the Exchange Server

```
$search = <<<END
<?xml version="1.0"?><a:searchrequest xmlns:a="DAV:" xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/security/">
<a:sql>SELECT "DAV:displayname",
"urn:schemas:httpmail:from",
"urn:schemas:httpmail:subject",
"urn:schemas:httpmail:textdescription",
"urn:schemas:httpmail:htmldescription",
"urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment",
"urn:schemas:httpmail:attachmentfilename",
"urn:schemas:httpmail:sender" FROM "$mailbox" WHERE "DAV:isfolder"=False AND "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/outlookmessageclass"='IPM.NOTE'</a:sql>
</a:searchrequest>
END
```

This works however the return comes back as

```
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[10]
      public '_attr' => 
        object(stdClass)[11]
      public 'A_STATUS' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[12]
              public '_attr' => 
                object(stdClass)[13]
                  ...
              public '_text' => string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' (length=15)
      public 'A_PROP' => 
        array
          0 => 
            object(stdClass)[14]
              public '_attr' => 
                object(stdClass)[15]
                  ...
              public 'A_DISPLAYNAME' => 
                array
                  ...
              public 'D_FROM' => 
                array
                  ...
              public 'D_SUBJECT' => 
                array
                  ...
              public 'D_TEXTDESCRIPTION' => 
                array
                  ...
              public 'D_HTMLDESCRIPTION' => 
                array
                  ...
              public 'D_HASATTACHMENT' => 
                array
                  ...  
    1 => 
      object(stdClass)[28]
        public '_attr' => 
          object(stdClass)[29]
        public 'A_STATUS' => 
          array
            0 => 
            object(stdClass)[30]
              public '_attr' => 
                object(stdClass)[31]
                  ...
              public '_text' => string 'HTTP/1.1 404 Resource Not Found' (length=31)
        public 'A_PROP' => 
          array
            0 => 
              object(stdClass)[32]
                public '_attr' => 
                  object(stdClass)[33]
                    ...
                public 'D_ATTACHMENTFILENAME' => 
                  array
                    ...
                public 'D_SENDER' => 
                  array
                    ...
```

Whether a file is attached or not, D_ATTACHMENTFILENAME is returned with a 404.  Any ideas why?

tl;dr - cannot retrieve list of attached files for emails through a webdav service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the filenames of the attachments using a Search request. Instead, filter on items which have the hasattachment set to 1. Foreach each of those elements, issue an [X-MS-ENUMATTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa126042%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx) request to get the attachment properties.

Comment: I should have marked this sooner, but I found the answer on my own and forgot to come check on this.  Still a great answer, hopefully next time I do this i'll remember the reference.  Thanks Henning!